# shell script performance improvement

Tags: shell, sed, sh, cut

I have developed a below script to preprocess a file
I'm trying to extract the timestamp from the header of the file and delete the some characters at the end of every line based on the length of the timestamp. once deleted, it then appends the timestamps to every line in the file. this script takes nearly 30 mins to process a 4 GB file.
is there a way I can increase the performance ? does this script be written in a better way?

```
if [ -f INPUT.TXT ]; then
                echo "FILE exists."
                date=$(cut -c8-25 INPUT.TXT | head -1)
                date_format=$(echo $date | sed -e "s/\./\:/g")
                echo -e " header date value is : $date"
                echo -e "Header date value format is: $date_format"
                leng_t=${#date_format}
                len=`expr $leng_t + 1`
                sed -i "s/.\{${len}\}$//" INPUT.TXT
                sed -i s/$/$date_format/ INPUT.TXT
        else
                echo "FILE does not exist."
        fi
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts(code), please do mention samples of your input file and expected output so that we can get a better picture of your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- The main optimization is obtained by combining two consecutive `sed`'s into one.
  Instead:

  ```sh
  sed -i "s/.\{${len}\}$//" INPUT.TXT
  sed -i s/$/$date_format/ INPUT.TXT
  ```

  Use:

  ```sh
  sed -i "s/.\{$len\}$/$date_format/" INPUT.TXT
  ```

  This should cut execution time up to twice.
  This result is the base result for showing the gain for all subsequent optimizations.

All subsequent optimizations require additional disk space to store a copy of the `INPUT.TXT` file (i.e. an additional 4 GB):

- Try putting the result in a separate file instead of editing it in place:

  ```sh
  sed "s/.\{$len\}$/$date_format/" INPUT.TXT >INPUT.tmp.TXT
  mv -f INPUT.tmp.TXT INPUT.TXT
  ```

  This save ~10% relative base result.
- On a multi-core machine, this shoud run faster:

  ```sh
  rev INPUT.TXT | sed "s/^.\{$len\}//" | rev | sed "s/\$/$date_format/" >INPUT.tmp.TXT
  mv -f INPUT.tmp.TXT INPUT.TXT
  ```

  This save ~35% relative base result.
- On a multi-core machine, and if there are no multibyte characters in the replacement (because [`cut` still can't handle it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163725/170894)):

  ```sh
  let cut_len=$len+1
  rev INPUT.TXT | cut -c $cut_len- | rev | sed "s/\$/$date_format/" >INPUT.tmp.TXT
  mv -f INPUT.tmp.TXT INPUT.TXT
  ```

  This save ~50% relative base result.

Thus, with the best optimization, the script can run four times faster.
*Note*: All tests done with 400MB file.